# Android Activity launch based on internet availablity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi developer i am every new to android application development.

My requirement is based on internet availability i have to show different activity.

I have two screen  A and B.

When internet available i directly navigate to screen B.

When internet not available it will show screen A.

It always check about internet availability and if is not available it always show screen A.

What is best approach to achieve this functionality.

Comment: i am not sure.you can check internet present or not .if present `setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout); `else `{another setContentView}` .Try this way .

Comment: sorry for lack of explanation. My screen A will design to shown some animation and not internet available message provide  an option for check setting and retry. My requirement is that when ever my app launch i will check internet available and if internet not available it show screen A otherwise it will directly navigate to screen B

Answer (score 0):

No need to keep two screens/Activities to check for internet availability.
It could be achieved using single screen/Activity.

All you need to do hide/show elements trick depending upon internet availability on the device.

This is how i generally do it in all my Android Applications:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/rl_internet"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/connection_lost"
        android:id="@+id/internet_lost_img"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONNECTION LOST!!"
        android:layout_below="@+id/internet_lost_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/connection_lost_header"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/connection_lost_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Please check Internet Settings"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/connection_check_txt"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/connection_check_txt"
        android:id="@+id/OR_txt"
        android:text="OR"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/OR_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
        android:text="RE-TRY"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/retry"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the inner relative layout named as 'rl_internet' consists of layout showing internet not available msg with visibility set as **'gone'**

You check if Internet is available in onCreate() method and if internet is not available you basically set the visibility of that relative layout as visible and making the rest of elements on screen invisible.

**If internet is available:

   no need to do anything

else:

   rl_internet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)**

Hope you get the idea!

Comment: It is good idea to check internet availability at time of splash screen lauch. based on that i will show screen

Comment: yes..infact because connection might get lost while switching between activities inside App..you could use the above approach inside any activity which needs internet connection..

Comment: My Screen A is common which show some animation and internet not available message.And give user to two option check setting or retry.Screen A activity launch whenever internet is not available. ie at the time of app launch or  app is running.

Comment: SO is knowledge sharing website and not merely Q&A website where you would be given complete answer to your question..through my answer I tried to provide solution which is generally used in almost any app to deal with internet connectivity check..if that helped great and if not hope you might figure it out your own way..Happy Coding :)